# Need to learn BootStrap for Angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am basically a PHP developer, but interested in javascript, so learned angularjs and jquery by own. The recent update I got is only learning angular is not enough, need to learn bootstrap also. But I really scared of CSS, because need to deal with pixels and have to design such a way that it has to fit for any device.

Bootstrap does that, ok fine, but how to keep in mind those hundreds of css class names. Can you guys give me some tricks and clues on how to memorize the css classes. And what we have to know before designing a layout (Asking these silly question, because I am into css for the first time).

Comment: I say don't remember them.. add whatever class you came to know in a list like document. so that you can read/refer it later. (_easy to say but hard to follow_).

Comment: I suggest you to ask such doubts on Stackoverflow chat rooms from next time..  :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep in mind class names, you just have to know framework components purpose.

On first steps you just need to checkout BS components and feature list (grids, tables, buttons, js-features) and see how they work and how could be used in your projects.

Next step checkout show cases and examples - you will get to know how compose page using grids and how components works together.

On this stage you will have enough information to start develop with BS.

Later you will face a lot of issues for sure, but it will be concrete questions, which answers could be googled.